# how to download multiple files from search result

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net, web

I have a list of files i have found after a search on some website.There is a download button near each result.The thing is each button leads to another page and only in this new page
there is the button that really triggers the download.

At first, I thought to write a JavaScript with a loop that runs over the list and mimic the click function on each button.but because the another page i cant.

so how using c# i can get to the next page and start the download using the link in this new page?

edit: i was trying to get the webpage code with httpWebRequest and WebClient but the "href" attribute to the download was empty.What should i do?